# C#: base, virtual and override

Tags: c#, inheritance, keyword

I tried understanding these keywords via MSDN, but each one tied into another...
Can someone explain to me what they mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read a bit and document yourself ;-)

[The C# Station Tutorial-Lesson 9: Polymorphism](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson09.aspx)

`base` is the way you usually refer to the base class, called `super` in java if I am not wrong.

so when inside a method you write `base.Name` you are getting the `Name` property of the base class from which your class has inherited/derived.

Answer (score 5):

> base

This is a language keyword that is used to refer to the base class, the class that the current one inherits from (extends). When you create an instance of a class that extends another, that instance can also be treated or used as the base class.

> virtual

A function or property modifier that means the property or function can be overridden in an extending class (class that inherits from the base class that defines the property or function). The overriding function or property must have the same signature as the original definition, but the implementation can be changed. A virtual function or property must be implemented immediately in the class where it is defined, whereas an abstract method or property is only implemented in the extending class.

> override

Is a function or property modifier used to indicate to the compiler that the following function or property extends or overrides the equivalent function or property from the base class.

Answer (score 2):

`base`: used when using members which are defined on a base type rather than the current type.

`virtual`: Methods and properties can be virtual, which means that they can be overridden by more specialized classes.

`override`: When a virtual method shall be overridden with a new implementation in a descending class, you have to use this keyword instead of `virtual`.

Example:

```
class A {
  public void X() {}
  public virtual void Y() {}
}

class B: A {
  public new void X() {} // defines a new method which does not override A.X

  public override void Y() { // override A.Y with a new implementation
    base.Y(); // calls the A.Y implementation
  }

  public virtual void Z() {} // additional virtual method on B
}

A a = new B();
a.X(); // calls A.X, not B.X
a.Y(); // calls B.Y because it is virtual and overridden
a.Z(); // syntax error - Z does not exist on an instance of type A
```